# Calculate probability of a simple scenario

Tags: probability

**Consider the following scenario:**

You're given 4 facedown cards and you know that two of them are red and the other two are black. Now you have to choose randomly 2 of the cards. What's the probability that the 2 chosen cards are of the same colour?

This is actually taken from a book with mathematical riddles and the given solution is 1 to 3.
I would have assumed that the solution is simply 50% and that the probability that second card has the same colour as the first card is 33% (e.g. first card is red -> only one of the remaining 3 cards is red -> 1/3).

Comment: If you choose a card, put it back and then choose a card again, the probability for the same colour is in fact $\frac{1}{2}$, but this is not the case. You choose two cards WITHOUT replacement.

Comment: Well, "$1:3$" can also mean "one out of three", which is correct. In daily life, it often means $1$ against $3$, asy ou interpreted it. Therefore, such formulations can be confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $6$ possibilities to choose two cards out of $4$. In two cases, you get the same colour. So, the probability is $\frac{1}{3}$

An even easier way to get the result. Choose an arbitary card. The probability that the other card fits is $\frac{1}{3}$ because one has the same and two the other colour.

The catch in the $50-50$-argument is that after one card has been chosen, you do not have four cards anymore.

Answer (score 2):

what are the possibilities in your favour?
Either Both cards are red or both are black!

so there are only two possibilities.
There are $^4C_2$  ways of drawing two cards from 4 cards.

$\frac{2}{^4C_2}=\frac{2}{6}=\frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

You have 1+1 good out of ${4\choose 2 } = 6$ outcomes.

It is ${2\over 6}= {1\over 3}$.